# Installing Ubuntu on Ryzen - AMD-VI: IOAPIC[17] not in IVRS table

Tags: system-installation, amd-processor, firmware

I thought I would have the best chance of installing Ubuntu on my new Ryzen 1700 by using the [Zesty release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/daily-live/current/) in order to get the very latest kernel. Unfortunately, I get the following error when trying to run the installer:

[image]

I made sure to install the latest version of the BIOS ([0503](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/HelpDesk_Download/)) on the motherboard (An [ASUS B350-PLUS](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/)), but that didn't resolve the issue. In case it matters, I am running 32 GB of [Corsair vengeance DDR4 memory.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B014UYPEXE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Does anyone know how I might resolve this issue, or know another Linux distro I might have better luck with getting running on Ryzen?

Comment: Looks like you aren't the only one having problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1671360

Answer (score 1):

This was a really dumb mistake, but one of the DIMMS was not properly fitted. I still get those error messages flash past not, but I get past it and into the installation.